# regx or pattern - How to prevent entering same character more than one time?

Tags: javascript, regex

am trying to allow text field to be entered only decimal and number values as follow

below are valid

```
 .099
  .8
  10
  99.9
  2.9
  4.88
  0.0
```

invalid

```
abc
ac$%$
asdf90
09.89abg#$#
-903abe
+8938/.99
....90.97
```

everything is fine so far. but i want to highlight the text field border the moment if user give only decimal point or more than one decimal point without numbers. the highlight should get removed when he gives valid input.

how to make it very simple the below code.

```
<input type = "text" maxlength = 4, value ="0.0", min=0 max=100/>

$(key).bind("#txtOne", function(obj){ // but i dont know why this Jquery allow character be entered sometimes
    let numberOnly=/^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$/;                    
    if (!numberOnly) {
        return obj.preventDefault();
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}); 

$("#txtOne").on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {    //after including this, working as expect 
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

help would be much appreicated. thanks in advance

if possible please give me some fiddle example

Comment: Can you give some invalid case?

Comment: hi @TreeNguyen pls check i have edited my post with invalid data.

thanks for jumping into this

Comment: Can't you simply check for `isNaN` on `keyup` instead of checking for individual keys?

Comment: i tried but some how i am failed with other special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using this regex:

```
^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$
```

This regex allows letters because it has `.`, which matches everything except line endings. The `\\` part is *not* escaping it to match a literal `.`.

To fix this, try removing one of the `\`. This is inside the delimiters `\...\`, so you don't need to escape the `\`s .

Alternatively, I wrote this regex:

```
^(?:[+-])?(?:\d*\.)?\d+$
```

Which also matches positive and negative signs.

EDIT:

I just tested your regex and found that it doesn't match leading or trailing periods like `.999` or `123.`.

Try my regex online here: https://regex101.com/r/eSM2CK/1

Comment: `^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$` will accept `123.` which is not valid number. Also, it requires number before decimal point, `.8` will be invalid. Solve it by using `^\d*(\.\d+)?$`

Comment: could you pls fiddle this. so that i can get clear idea.

Comment: @Idiot_cheg Sorry but I know little about jquery. Most of the code should be the same, just replace your regex with mine: `let numberOnly=/^(?:[+-])?(?:\d*\.)?\d+$/;`

Comment: @Sweeper your patter is almost matching .. thanks for the lead man

Comment: sorry man, am not mentioning your answer as "almost" . i meant about my extra css work..

Answer (score 3):

So what you are trying to achieve is not stopping people to not entering decimal point continuously, but to force the user to input a number. I have made a small code to show you how it works

```
$("input").on("input", function() { //on user input
    const value = $(this).val();
  if (isNaN(value)) { // check if this is a number. '1.0' is a number. '1.0.a' is not'
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  } else {
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
  }
})
```

Running fiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyxm8mq8/)

Comment: what the hell.?? this is so simple than i thought.. i never saw girl with awesome tech brain.. thanks @treeNguyen .. how did achieve the same with REGEX

Comment: you are trying to achieve checking for number in regex?